# Docusign API Explorer is Not working with Custom Fields?

Tags: docusignapi

Here is what I did:

1. Created a Template in my Demo Account with three tabs. 3 default (Full name, Last name and Email) and 1 custom (BillingAddress)
2. Use the API to send this new template to a particular name and email address. (Using API Explorer and by going to "Request a Signature") and pass parameters for only one tab (Email).
3. The document goes for signature but the tab is not visible on the document.

Can someone guess what is going wrong? I have attached a partial screenshot of the API Explorer page as well.

Thanks
Rohit

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Seems like perhaps you're misunderstanding how the **Email** tab works.

If you've placed an **Email** tab in the Template itself (i.e., when creating the Template using the DocuSign web console), then DocuSign will automatically put the Email Address of the recipient (who 'owns' that tab) in that location when the Envelope is created -- you don't ever need to supply a value for an Email tab (because its value is automatically set to the recipient's Email address when the Envelope is created).

On the other hand, if you're trying to add another (additional) value to the Envelope's document(s) -- that contains an email address you specify in the "Create Envelope" API request (i.e., not necessarily the Email Address that corresponds to the recipient who owns that tab) -- then you don't want to use an **Email** tab, you should use a **Text** tab instead. By using a **Text** tab, you get the ability to explicity set its value in the "Create Envelope" API request. When you create the text tab, be sure to populate (at a minimum) the fields I show populated here:

[image: IODocs]